# How do I deploy local data files to my phone along with my app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, local-storage

The following is in regards to [Xamarin.](https://www.xamarin.com/)

I recently deployed my app to my phone using [Free Provisioning.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)

So my app is pulling data from a directory inside of the projects directory called [projectname]datafiles, although when I deploy it to my phone, when I search/query the data it crashes the app, so I'm guessing that the data is not actually there so my guess is that it actually hasn't even been deployed to the device within the package contents of the app, my question is...

Does anyone know how to add these data files to the deployment of the app so I can use the app fully functioning?

Thank you,

Luke.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy files with your app package by marking them as Build Action "Content" or by placing them in the Resources folder as "Bundled Resources".

See the [File System](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) docs for more info.

Comment: This is the one I'm looking for - 




`var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("./");
foreach (var directory in directories)`




I need to edit this but with my directories but I dont know where to put the data files and wherever i put them how i find the directory.

Comment: check these out if you would please :) -

http://pasteboard.co/1111V1Kw.png and http://pasteboard.co/1112RdDa.png